# Vuetify insert action button in data-table and get row data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

Environment:

```
vue@^2.6.10:
vuetify@^2.1.0
```

I want to use `v-data-table` to show search results and add evaluate button in each row in the `v-data-table`.

Unfortunately I have two issues:

1. Evaluate buttons are not shown
2. I don't know how to get row data of pushed button

What do I need to change?

Template

```
    <v-data-table
            :headers="headers"
            :items="search_result"
    >
        <template slot="items" slot-scope="row">
            <td>{{row.item.no}}</td>
            <td>{{row.item.result}}</td>
            <td>
                <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark small color="pink">
                    <v-icon dark>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </td>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Script

```
data () {
            return {
                headers: [
                    { text: 'no', value: 'no' },
                    { text: 'result', value: 'result' },
                    { text: 'good', value: 'good'},
                ],
                // in real case initial search_result = [], and methods: search function inject below data
                search_result: [{no: 0, result: 'aaa'}, {no:2, result: 'bbb'],
            }
        },
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

1. slot name used to "replace the default rendering of a row" is `item`, not `items`
2. Add wrapping `<tr>` into slot template
3. Just add `@click="onButtonClick(row.item)` to `v-btn` and create method `onButtonClick`

```html
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="search_result">
      <template v-slot:item="row">
          <tr>
            <td>{{row.item.no}}</td>
            <td>{{row.item.result}}</td>
            <td>
                <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark small color="pink" @click="onButtonClick(row.item)">
                    <v-icon dark>mdi-heart</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </td>
          </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

```js
methods: {
    onButtonClick(item) {
      console.log('click on ' + item.no)
    }
  }
```

## Note..

...solution above is replacing default row rendering with your own so expect some of the `v-data-table` features to **not work** (didn't try but I expect row selection, grouping, in place editing etc. will be broken). If that's problem for you, here is alternative solution:

1. Add one more column to your headers definition: `{ text: "", value: "controls", sortable: false }`
2. Do not override `item` slot (row rendering). Override `item.controls` slot instead. Notice "controls" is the same as in column definition - we are overriding just rendering of "controls" column
3. Everything else is same

```html
    <v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="search_result">
      <template v-slot:item.controls="props">
        <v-btn class="mx-2" fab dark small color="pink" @click="onButtonClick(props.item)">
          <v-icon dark>mdi-heart</v-icon>
        </v-btn>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

Comment: Great, just what I was looking for too. Does it however not affect some built-in functionality of the data-table?

Comment: @user1729972 It probably does as you are replacing default row rendering template with your own. Good point. I''ll add alternative solution to my answer...

Answer (score 0):

In my case the solution of Michal was throwing the following exception

[image]

The solution was using `slot` and `slot-scope`

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="items"
        class="elevation-1"
    >
        <template slot="item.delete" slot-scope="props">
            <v-btn class="mx-2" icon @click="() => delete(props.item)">
                <v-icon dark>mdi-delete</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
        </template>
    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            headers: [
                // Dynamic headers
                {
                    text: 'Name',
                    value: 'name'
                },
                {
                    text: '',
                    // Row to replace the original template
                    value: 'delete'
                },
            ],
            items: [
                {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'A'
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'B'
                }
            ]
        };
    },
    methods: {
        delete(item) {
            this.items = this.items.filter((d) => d.id !== item.id);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```