# Vue - button is not visible inside v-data-table

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuetify-tabs

I have a problem with v-data-table. I want to add button for edit, delete and add new product to my v-data-table. Data comes from my rest api and is assign via my getter CARS to v-data-table. Everything is fine and every single row is displayed but button is not shown.... I tried a lot of different approaches but it still doesn't work..
I would be grateful if You help me. 
Best regards!

Here is my code.

```
<v-data-table
    v-model="selected"
  :headers="headers"
  :items=CARS
  :single-select="singleSelect"
   item-key="id"
    show-select class="elevation-1" 
>
  <template slot="items" slot-scope="props">


      <td>{{ props.item.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.vin }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.register_number}}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.cost}}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.latitude }}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.longitude}}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.service}}</td>
      <td>{{ props.item.reservation}}</td>
       <td class="justify-content-left layout">
      <v-btn icon @click.prevent="editUser(props.item)">
         <v-icon color="blue">edit</v-icon>
      </v-btn>
      </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: did you import the `v-btn` component?

Comment: When I place v-btn under </v-data-table> then I can see him. So it must be imported I think

Comment: then i'd recommend to make another component instead of using another template.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuetify insert action button in data-table and get row data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59081299/vuetify-insert-action-button-in-data-table-and-get-row-data)

Comment: @MichalLevý Yes! It worked! thanks

Comment: I think you are using old version of Vuetify. Please update your Vue and Vuetify version and try like this example. [v-data-table crud actions](https://codepen.io/pen/?&editable=true&editors=101)